# Does stencil use tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, stenciljs

I am using Visual Studio Code for developing web components with help of stencil. Writing a basic component requires using decorators in typescript file. Visual Studio Code showed me a error message, because, decorators are not supported by default in typescript. Creating tsconfig.json in the root directory and adding this `"experimentalDecorators": true` to it, suppressed the warning. Now I am wondering, would stencil compiler use this config for typescript handling or it is just a config for some IDE specific tool?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Stencil uses the `tsconfig.json` from your project for the TypeScript transpilation step, but overwrites certain values of the `compilerOptions`. At the time of writing this, those are:

```
compilerOptions.isolatedModules = false;
compilerOptions.suppressOutputPathCheck = true;
compilerOptions.allowNonTsExtensions = true;
compilerOptions.removeComments = false;
compilerOptions.sourceMap = false;
compilerOptions.lib = undefined;
compilerOptions.types = undefined;
compilerOptions.noEmit = undefined;
compilerOptions.noEmitOnError = undefined;
compilerOptions.rootDirs = undefined;
compilerOptions.declaration = undefined;
compilerOptions.declarationDir = undefined;
compilerOptions.out = undefined;
compilerOptions.outFile = undefined;
compilerOptions.outDir = undefined;
```

See [src/compiler/transpile/transpile-service.ts#L72-L89](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/65aeb8c4a818b200695946073b71f63bf4aa3634/src/compiler/transpile/transpile-service.ts#L72-L89).

`experimentalDecorators` is a feature that is also used by Stencil and should therefore be enabled in your tsconfig. You can have a look at the [tsconfig of the stencil-app-starter](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-app-starter/blob/master/tsconfig.json) for the recommended values.